# JavaFX Как в лайв режиме проврить checkbox на галочку

Tags: java, javafx

Привет всем,

Я в JavaFX новечек и хотел бы узнать как сделать так, чтобы если допустим CheckBox был нажат то SplitMenuButton становилась в режим disable или наоборот.

Comment: повесить на CheckBox слушателя и при нажатии делать то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого необходимо использовать [selectedProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/CheckBox.html#selectedProperty--). Необходимо повесить на него листенер, и в листенере уже делать свои вещи.

Пример :

```
checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) - > {
    if (newValue && !oldValue) {
        //чекбокс был переведен с положение включено
    } else if (!newValue && oldValue) {
        //чекбокс был переведен с положение выключено
    }
});
```

Comment: Еще один вариант это использование bind: button.disableProperty().bind(checkBox.selectedProperty());